# Choosing a loss function for minimize total sum

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, regression

I've the following regression problem. I'm forecasting a random variable $X$ for every day of a month, represented as $X_{ij}$ where $i$ is the day of the month and $j$ is the month number. I care if the total at the end of the month is within what was committed (say $C_{0j}$). I get the $X_{ij}$ values in sequence, i.e. every day ${X_{0j}, X_{1j}...}$. I also have historical values of $X_{ij}$ and $C_{0j}$ to train on. I needed help in understanding if I've set up my data right for training a machine learned model. My current set up is to use 31 models, each for a day into the month and to use MSE as loss function. For e.g. model $M_3$ would train on data

$X_{train} = {X_{1j}, X_{2j}, X_{3j}}$ and $Y_{train} = (\sum_{4}^{30}X_{ij}) - C_{0j}$ $\forall j$ using MSE as loss function.

Likewise for $M_4$ the set up would look like

$X_{train} = {X_{1j}, X_{2j}, X_{3j}, X_{4j}}$ and $Y_{train} = (\sum_{5}^{30}X_{ij}) - C_{0j}$ $\forall j$ using MSE as loss function, and so on...

Could someone help validate if this set up is right? I'm unsure of the right loss function. For e.g. why not RMSE or MAE ?

Comment: So C represents the summation of Xs in a month right?  Also, Can you explain why you have Xij 4 to 30 in the loss function instead of 1 to 29-31?

Comment: Yes, C represents the summation of Xs in a month. The reason it is 4 is because $M_3$ will seek to predict the 4th day's value given the 1st 3 days values. Likewise $M_4$ would seek to explain the 5th day's values given the 1st 4 days values and so on.

Comment: Isn't it more logical to define loss as  Mn+ (∑30\n Xij)−C0j ∀j since C0 includes Ms? Otherwise, your loss function converges, but it must predict wrong predictions for expected values for the optimal occasion.

Comment: Probably not, is my thinking. If I read your suggestion right, you want to include $M_3$ prediction in the modeling of $M_4$ ? But this is not needed, as on day 4 the true data $X_{3j}$ would already be present.

Comment: Yes but if you do this you'll have the wrong objective. Let me explain what I mean with an example: Let's say you are on day 29 and you'll predict day 30. Your loss function on this occasion is (X30j-C0j)^2. In order to optimize this, you have to update X30j as C0j itself. In other words, each time you go on month days you'll have to update your predictions higher. Normally many to many networks like LSTMs have the exact expected output, I couldn't get why you are trying to include C0j rather than each real Xij (If not having data I don't think it's possible to create a day prediction model)

Comment: The reason $C_{0j}$ is used is because at any given point in the month the system needs to predict what the monthly total is going to be.

Comment: Then isn't better to predict directly C0j rather than predicting a sequence of Xijs.